# Angular on Docker hot reload not works

Tags: angular, docker

I have a docker-compose.yml file with several services, two of them are Angular and Django, the problem is when I change the code in the Angular container the changes are not reflected automatically but instead it works in Django.

Dockerfile-angular:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./frontend/project/package.json .
RUN nom install
COPY ./frontend/project .
CMD npm start
```

docker-compose.yml

```
...
django:
  ...
  volumes:
    - ./backend/project:/youngtalentreturn
angular:
  ...
  volumes:
    - ./frontend/project/src:/usr/src/app/src
    - ./frontend/project/node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Anybody cloud help me please ?

Comment: If you run `npm start` from your host system, without Docker involved, does it do what you expect?  You can use that for ordinary development, delete the `volumes:` from the Compose setup, and then use the Docker setup for final integration testing and deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with poll param on start command

-- poll 2000

Answer (score 1):

I made a [Docker-Angular Hot-Reload template](https://github.com/Rehost-Startup/template-angular) for future projects.

Inside docker, we need to pass the following flags with `ng serve` command for polling to work:

- `--poll 2000`
- `--disable-host-check`

And, just to be sure, set the environment HOST as `0.0.0.0`.

PS: The solution is not mine. I found it on one of the Github Issue Threads.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I've added the explanation around the link. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why you consider the second part necessary? The currently  accepted answer does not have it.

Comment: It didn't work me without it. And, I found this solution on a Github Issue that suggested me this. Either disable-hot-check or tell Docker to get HOST address as 0.0.0.0. Doing one of the following would get the project running. My environment:
- Windows WSL2
- Docker base image: node:alpine

I've tested this solution all 3 major platforms: MacOS, Windows, Linux.